# How to keep WSL2 intact when updating from Windows 10 to Windows 11

Tags: windows-10, windows-11

I'm using WSL2 for my development work, and I would like some hints on what to expect when upgrading from Windows 10 to Windows 11.

What happens with existing config inside of WSL2? Will anything work any longer?

Comment: I would always assume the worst on Windows. But the config should be a file that you can backup.

Comment: At this time, Windows 11 is essentially Windows 10, as time goes on that will change.  Windows 11 has some new features, but with regards to WSL, very little has change except for WSLg support.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, Windows 11 and Windows 10 are very similar,
but theory doesn't always work.

See this user testimony :
[WSL2 stopped working after one of the recent Windows 11 updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/911582/wsl2-stopped-working-after-one-of-the-recent-windo.html).

WSL in Windows 11 is being heavily upgraded and this is an
ongoing process. Microsoft does not guarantee support in Windows 11
for older WSL versions.

In short, you upgrade at your own risk. Even if it works, there is no
guarantee that it will continue on working.

You have 10 days after the upgrade to Windows 11 to rollback the upgrade.
After this period, going back to Windows 10 will require re-installation.